# How to add a "division" between buttons in GUI Status

Tags: user-interface, status, sap-gui, dynpro

I would like to know what I have to write/input in GUI Status so I can get a division pipe.

It should appear like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, left click on the field and select "separation line".

Thank you anyway.

Comment: please check out the proposed SAP stack and help get it started, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products